# using memcmp for image matching?

Tags: c, rgb, bmp, memcmp

As per my understanding, a typical BMP format store pixel data from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner. So I have 
`unsigned char* screenshotArray` and `unsigned char* croppedArray` with rgb value from 24bit bmp.

this is my attempt to write a code to match the rgb of a bmp and return me the coordinate when it's matched:

```c
#include <stdio.h>   // Include standard input/output library for printing messages
#include <stdlib.h>  // Include standard library for memory management
#include <windows.h> // Include the Windows API for screen capture

int main()
{
    FILE *log = fopen("log.txt", "w");

    // Load the BMP image from Microsoft Paint 24-bit BMP
    int croppedWidth, croppedHeight;

    FILE *file = fopen("cropped.bmp", "rb"); // Open the BMP image file in binary read mode
    if (!file)                               // Check if the file couldn't be opened
    {
        fprintf(log, "Failed to open the cropped image file.\n"); // Print an error message to the standard error stream
        return 1;                                                    // Return an error code and exit
    }

    // Read the BMP header to get image dimensions
    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_SET);                   // Move the file pointer to the width field in the BMP header
    fread(&croppedWidth, sizeof(int), 1, file);  // Read the width of the image
    fseek(file, 22, SEEK_SET);                   // Move the file pointer to the height field in the BMP header
    fread(&croppedHeight, sizeof(int), 1, file); // Read the height of the image

    // Calculate the size of the cropped image
    int cropWidthRGB = 3 * croppedWidth;                                     // Calculate the size of one row RGB of the image
    int croppedImageSize = cropWidthRGB * croppedHeight;                     // Calculate the total size of the image needed
    unsigned char *croppedArray = (unsigned char *)malloc(croppedImageSize); // Allocate memory to store the image
    if (!croppedArray)                                                       // Check if memory allocation failed
    {
        fclose(file);                                                          // Close the image file
        fprintf(log, "Failed to allocate memory for the cropped image.\n"); // Print an error message
        return 1;                                                              // Return an error code and exit
    }

    // Read the pixel data of the cropped image
    fseek(file, 54, SEEK_SET);                      // Move the file pointer to the start of the pixel data
    fread(croppedArray, 1, croppedImageSize, file); // Read the pixel data into the allocated memory
    fclose(file);                                   // Close the image file

    // Capture a 1920x1080 screenshot
    int screenWidth = 1920;
    int screenHeight = 1080;
    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(NULL); // Get a handle to the screen device context

    // Create a compatible DC and bitmap to store the screenshot
    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);                                        // Create a compatible device context
    HBITMAP hBitmapScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, screenWidth, screenHeight); // Create a compatible bitmap
    SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmapScreen);                                               // Select the bitmap into the device context
    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);         // Copy the screen content to the bitmap

    // Get the pixel data of the screenshot
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmiHeader.biWidth = screenWidth;
    bmiHeader.biHeight = screenHeight; // Use a positive value
    bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    int screenImageSize = screenWidth * 3 * screenHeight;                                                            // Calculate the size of RGB of the screenshot
    unsigned char *screenshotArray = (unsigned char *)malloc(screenImageSize);                                       // Allocate memory to store the screenshot
    GetDIBits(hScreenDC, hBitmapScreen, 0, screenHeight, screenshotArray, (BITMAPINFO *)&bmiHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS); // Retrieve the pixel data

    // Clean up screenshot resources
    DeleteObject(hBitmapScreen); // Delete the bitmap
    DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);         // Delete the device context
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreenDC);  // Release the screen device context

    // Find the exact match
    int screenXMax = screenWidth - croppedWidth;
    int screenYMax = screenHeight - croppedHeight;
    int matchX = -1;
    int matchY = -1;

    // Iterate through the screenshot and find the matching region
    for (int screenY = 0; screenY <= screenYMax; screenY++)
    {
        for (int screenX = 0; screenX <= screenXMax; screenX++)
        {
            int match = 1;
            // Compare pixel blocks using memcmp for faster comparison
            for (int croppedY = 0; croppedY < croppedHeight; croppedY++)
            {
                int offsetCropped = cropWidthRGB * croppedY;                           // Calculate the starting position in the cropped image
                int offsetScreen = 3 * ((screenY + croppedY) * screenWidth + screenX); // Calculate the starting position in the screenshot
                // Compare entire pixel blocks using memcmp
                if (memcmp(&screenshotArray[offsetScreen], &croppedArray[offsetCropped], cropWidthRGB) != 0)
                {
                    match = 0; // Not a match
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (match)
            {
                matchX = screenX;                                // Record the x-coordinate of the match
                matchY = screenHeight - croppedHeight - screenY; // Record the y-coordinate of the match
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchX >= 0) // post-checking, if not found proceed to next row
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Save match coordinates to a file
    FILE *matchFile = fopen("match_coordinates.txt", "w"); // Open a file to write the match coordinates
    if (matchX != -1)
    {
        fprintf(matchFile, "Image match found at (%d, %d)\n", matchX, matchY); // Print the coordinates to the file
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(matchFile, "Image match not found.\n"); // Print a message indicating no match
    }
    fclose(matchFile); // Close the file
    fclose(log);       // Close the file


    // Clean up memory
    free(croppedArray);    // Free the memory allocated for the cropped image
    free(screenshotArray); // Free the memory allocated for the screenshot

    return 0; // Exit the program
}
```

My code work for smaller bmp.

edit: I think I know the reason, some dimension will do padding so we need to skip it before store it to array. However I am still not sure do GetDIBits perform padding as well

Comment: You might like to involve the `stride` of the image, since each row of bytes of a .bmp image is a multiple of `4`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) says: *The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes (a 32-bit DWORD) by padding.*

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I modified the code and change my question, can you spot any mistake?

Comment: @WeatherVane the bmp is from mspaint which is guaranteed 24bit thought, I modified it but it still can't match larger bmp

Comment: @Eric it is the sizes smaller than 32-bit that might, like 24. If there are say 3 pixels across, it needs 12 bytes per row, not 9. So you can't compute the row index from the pixel width * 3.

Comment: @WeatherVane In my understanding multiple 24-bit BMP images with different dimensions will have the same stride as long as they are 24-bit images.
you mean `int cropWidthRGB = 3 * croppedWidth;` is wrong?

Comment: The image size isn't imagewidth * imageheight * 3. It is rowlength * imageheight.

Comment: the arraylength have to * 3 due to rgb pixel

Comment: As stated the row length must be a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: I've written a c code to test it, pretty sure the width isn't 4

Comment: If you don't like to take the theoretical approach, try a practical one: Insert debug outputs with the hex of the pixel that do not match, including the coordinates. Then try to find a pattern. You might want to start a bit before and a span of several dozens.

Comment: I tried, I can only test small picture, large picture takes forever to output. For small picture, the code above is working, but large picture is wrong. I ran out of options. I tried 4 as well but that didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "_take forever to output_"? What do you think takes so long?

Comment: @thebusybee I output the hexadecimal for both picture so I can inspect if there is something wrong, but when the image is huge then it takes long time to output. And text editor barely able to launch it because the text file get too huge

Comment: That's why I suggested to only output the range around the first mismatch. ;-) Less is more. Debug output does not help, if you cannot analyze the erroneous case.

Comment: Please do not add new information in comments, this is not the place. Instead, [edit] your question and add it there. -- The linked example cannot be compiled there.